# iPhone Parallax Background Image Resizing

Tags: joomla

I'm browsing but I can't find a solution. I have some parallax backgrounds as a dividers. In learning how to use the fixed background images, I discovered a potential issue with controlling how the background images display on mobile devices.

When I shrink my computer’s browser window, or load the sites into Responsinator, the backgrounds look fine. But when I view them on the actual iOS devices, they don’t look good. The mobile device just displays a highly zoomed-in portion of pixels that are in the center of the original image. There’s no resemblance to the desired background image, and it’s so enlarged that the pixelation creates a poor quality image.

You can check the site here:

[daremblum.com](http://daremblum.com)

Thanks in advance for any help.